# Cannot find dragging lines

Tags: node-editor

[image]

I dont know how I got this one. I cannot get the property panel. I dont see any short cut keys like T & N for the third panel? I don't also see the three lines in the corner to split the screen. There are only three dots that only moves up and down.
Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properties window missing?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94696/properties-window-missing)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have maximized your 3D view.

You can toggle this action with the shortcut keys  **CTRL** + **Up Arrow**  or with **SHFT** + **Spacebar**

Or find the option in the View menu

[image]

Comment: Thanks I got it 3fingeredfrog